# dataTable loads but throw undefined is not a function

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am loading a dataTable like this:

```
DataTables[ChartTableId] = $('#table_' + ChartTableId).dataTable({
            "data": ChartTable['table_data'],
            "columns": ChartTable['table_cols'],
            "deferRender": true,
            "scrollX": true,
            "scrollY": 290
        });
```

If I try to load it with some subset of data it work just fine (see http://debug.datatables.net/eyefad)

When I try to load it with another subset of data generate by the same code, the table loads properly but right after loading, it throws **"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"** (see http://debug.datatables.net/ewocis).

I looked to similar issues and apparently it might be caused by jquery being loaded twice. I inspected my source and I have no indication that jquery is included more than once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataTables were generated when my column titles were string but not integer.

The problem was fixed when all my column titles were converted to string before calling `dateTable`.